# How to set Style and Script for one Table but not other Tables?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, styled-components

I'm trying to use styles & scripts in One table but not in other tables.  Test keep showing styles & scripts affect ALL tables, how to correct this? Here is part of my code:

```
<table  onclick="getElement(event)"> 
<!--- style & script for this 'table' only ... how?  -->
<**style**>
td { text-align: center; }
th, td { border: 1px solid gray; }

.btn1 {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */
.btn2 {background-color: #008CBA;} /* Blue */
</style>

<**script**>
function getElement(e) {
    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var btnId = element.id;
ooo
</script>

<col style="width:82%"><col style="width:8%"><col >
<tr>
  <td>Description #1</td>
  <td><a href="/file1.mp4" download"></a>
    <button Id = "btn1-1" class="button btn1">mp4 </button></td>
  <td><a href="/file1.pdf" download"></a>
    <button Id = "btn2-1" class="button btn2" onClick=“???” >PDF</button></td>
</tr>
```

How to get one table's style and script different from others?

My tests kept showing Style and Script affected ALL my tables.

Comment: You can use CSS-Modules for that or make it so that the class is namespaced or just add multiple classes or give the parent of the table a class that is your context and use a more specific CSS-Rule.

Comment: By using an attribute `id="..."` in the table tag, referencing to your style.

Comment: Are you in control of the HTML? If so add a class or unique I’d to that table. If not, what is unique about that table? For example is it the only one to have that onclick attribute?

Comment: I'm using a 'class' since there are 20 <tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr> series in my HTML page.  All the <td>'s need the same <style>.  The <script> vary between "button btn1" and "button btn2".  Hope this helps clarify my setup.

Comment: Problem solved.  But { .btn1 {border: 1px ...} } still NOT working.  Assume it has to do with the order of things.

Thanks for the help with resolving my problem :)